# ASP.NET MVC 5 Images / Scripts Are Not Loading at Runtime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I had started messing around with ASP.NET MVC 5 (so far so good). ASP.NET MVC looks really cool and I am keen to learn more. I have been trying to set up a couple of web pages (views) for a test application. What I find odd, is that my images do not load despite them existing in the correct folders. I also noticed my css scripts don't seem to work. Here is the code for my images:

```
<div id="Features">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" align="center">
        <h2>Get Your Grocery List</h2>
        <img src="~/Images/grocerylist.jpg" width="200" height="200" id="mainImage"/>
        <p>With this application, you can rest assured you wont need to spend minutes drafting your grocery list - this application will generate a grocery list for you on the fly!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" align="center">
        <h2>Compare Grocery With Shops</h2>
        <img src="~/Images/CompareConsumerPricing.png" width="200" height="200" id="ConsumerPricing"/>
        <p>We know that different shops will have different prices. This application lets you list several shops and compare pricing - this means you will get the upper hand (bill shock will be a thing of the past)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
```

When I run my web application, I get this output:

[image]

I am using IIS on Visual Studio 2015 to test everything out. Is there something that I must add to the web config file? I have checked, the images and scripts do exist in the referenced URL.

EDIT: Here is my Solution Explorer (on Visual Studio 2015):

[image]

Comment: Can you display your solution explorer? otherwise it's hard to check what is wrong

Comment: Also what does your browser console say? Is there any errors or something?

Comment: There are some errors in the console, but I am not sure if these errors are related to the reason I am getting this error: The console. The last few lines of the console worry me: 

'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded '0nj1dcsi.4ol'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dnx.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'ues1gpid.2di'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
src="@Url.Content("~/Images/grocerylist.jpg")"
```

Comment: I flagged you because your reason isn't correct. Refer to your link!. This question nature needs such an answer.